# Package file without .rpm or .tar.gz... What to do?

Tags: rhel, software-installation, rpm, packaging

I'm busy installing ELK package on a few RHEL6 servers, but we have two mail servers which are still RHEL5 i386 servers.

So I go to https://www.elastic.co/downloads/logstash and downloaded the Linux 32-bit version, but the fun part is (for me) it is downloading a `logstash-forwarder_linux_386` package. No `.rpm` or `.tar.gz` behind it.

How i can "unzip" these?

Answer (score 2):

The file `logstash-forwarder_linux_386` is an executable. It's ready to run, there's no unzipping to be done. You can see that with the [`file` command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)):

```
$ file logstash-forwarder_linux_386
logstash-forwarder_linux_386: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
```

You need to make this file executable and place it in a directory where the rest of logstash will find it.

```
chmod a+rx logstash-forwarder_linux_386
sudo mv logstash-forwarder_linux_386 /usr/local/bin/
```

No, I don't know why they didn't bother to wrap it in a package.